# Calculating Fourier spectra of particle current autocorrelation functions

Tags: fourier-transform, correlation-functions, dispersion, molecular-dynamics, normal-modes

The particle current density can be defined as :
$$\textbf j(\textbf r,t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \textbf v_i\delta(\textbf r-\textbf r_i(t))$$
Its spatial Fourier transform :
$$\textbf j(\textbf k,t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\textbf v_ie^{-i\textbf k.\textbf r_i}$$
Now,considering the wave vector to be directed along x direction, longitudinal particle current autocorrelation function  is defined as :
$$C_L(\textbf k,t)=\frac{k^2}{N}\Big<j_x(\textbf k,t)j_x(-\textbf k,0)\Big>$$
In Molecular Dynamics ( MD ) simulations, it can be calculated and then it can be  Fourier transformed with respect to time to obtain $C_L(\textbf k,\omega)$. When the Fourier transform is performed, one obtains a complex quantity. I want to obtain wave dispersion relation from $C_L(\textbf k,\omega)$ data. For this purpose I need to plot $C_L(\textbf k,\omega)$ as a function of $\omega$. According to the standard method , the $\omega$ value where maximum of $C_L(\textbf k,\omega)$ occurs, is plotted w.r.t the corresponding $k$ value to obtain the dispersion curve.

My question is, when plotting $C_L(\textbf k,\omega)$ shall I plot it's magnitude ? I am unable to decide whether I should plot the magnitude of this complex quantity or, simply the real part or something else. My purpose is to finally obtain the dispersion relation for longitudinal wave in the system.